# Acentos y ñ con Spring

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Al incluir el multiidioma en mi web con Spring MVC definiendo los mensajes en un .properties

- mensaje.planificaciones = Plannings,
- mensaje.seguimientos = Tracing
- mensaje.administradores = Administrators
- mensaje.usuarios = Users

Al añadir estos mensajes al html no se reconocen las tildes ni las ñ, con th:text="#{mensaje.planificaciones}", ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-escale=1">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Custom styles for this template-->
<!--  <link href="/planiDeport-1/src/main/resources/templates/administrador/css/sb-admin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<link
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css"
    th:href="@{/css/style.css}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">

                    <h5 class="card-header" style="background-color: powderblue;" th:text="#{mensaje.planificaciones}"></h5>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado usar la etiqueta `meta` de HTML? La colocas en tu sección `<head>`. Así: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` Es la espcificación oficial para HTML5.

Comment: Si, pero sigue igual.

Comment: La solución ha sido la comentada por @Alvaro Sánchez pero en vez de hacerlo sobre los archivos html lo he hecho solo los .properties.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas trabajando con eclipse, coloque el ratón encima de su fichero html, haga click en el botón derecho de su ratón y pulse en properties y marque esta opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sigo obteniendo los mismos resultados.